# writing a http response (text file ) to a string

Tags: java, parsing

I am firing a http request to a server and the server returns a file.

File obtained from server is a csv file (text file). I intend to write the content of file to a String
or a StringBuffer. How can I do it?

```
response = getResponse(url);
StrigBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//TODO : write content of response to sb
```

I think I should get the input stream of response and go ahead. But how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I read/convert an InputStream to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to convert content of file (text or csv) in String.

```
    InputStream in;
    String str = "";
    try {
        in = new URL(url).openStream();
        int size = in.available();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            char ch = (char) in.read();
            str = str.concat(ch + "");
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```